# Can I ensure that every CentOS 7 has /etc/os-release file?

Tags: linux, centos, operating-system

I made a script, and it checks OS version in the beginning.
It reads /etc/os-release file, and checks whether the os is CentOS 7 or not.
But I'm not sure whether I can ensure that every CentOS 7 has that file.
Other OSs don't matter, but CentOS 7 matters.
Can I ensure this?
Is there any document about this?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you describe, the file /etc/os-release should do the work in any CentOS version, although you can also try to query the installed package centos-release, where you can find the same information: rpm -qi centos-release | grep Version

Comment: But it seems that CentOS 6.10 doesn't have such file. Instead, it has redhat-release, centos-release, etc. So I was wondering if the os-release file was only added to recent versions of OSs.

Comment: I am not sure when os-release was added to CentOS but anyway you could try these other methods,

Method 1: for i in $(ls /etc/*release); do echo $i; cat $i; done

Method 2: cat /etc/issue